# How do I take a 360 degree photo of myself without asking someone else to do it for me?

Tags: technology, photography

This is sort of an odd question, but here it goes:

Basically I want to make a 3D model of my head for a 3D printer. I am following [this](http://makezine.com/projects/make-ultimate-guide-to-3d-printing/print-your-head-in-3d/) guide. In order for the software to accurately recreate a virtual version of me, I need dozens of pictures of the lower and upper part of my head from all angles while I stay in a fixed position. I'm on a university campus and I've only been here for a week, so there's not really anyone I'm comfortable with asking to do this for me. I was hoping the creative people on this site could help me out.

I would like to be able to do this without spending money. Both my iPad Mini 4 and my Android phone can take fairly good quality photos.

Comment: Why don't you use a rotating office chair with a steady camera and rotate yourself slowly?

Answer (score 5):

To do this yourself, you'll need some equipment whether you make or borrow it.

You'll need a swivel chair to sit on, a means of holding your "camera" pointed at you as a tripod does, and a way to trip the shutter button of your "camera" to capture the images from eye-level and from above.

Your head and shoulders should practically fill the frame.

You'll take all the photos of yourself while sitting on the chair as you turn your seat on its axis. Two cameras working simultaneously can get the two series at once. One camera will make the two sessions difficult to match; but, it may be possible with varying degrees of success.

Try to provide a continuous even background for your portrait series. Fix the base of the seat so that you can minimize any movement sideways as you turn. A featureless background will lessen the possibility of the software substituting points from the background for your head.

The lighting should be even, indirect, and diffuse.

Shoot enough images (minimum 12 per camera position—more is better) so that enough points to track in each shot can be found in the next shot. The software will "look" for common matching coordinates in each image pair, pair-by-pair. More points that match with minimal change per image will allow finer stitching with better results in the plot.

TIP: Put Post-It notes or something similar on the walls at the same height around the room to help you gauge how much to turn your seat and to have something to look at and focus on for more consistent results.

That's it, simple but definitely NOT easy. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The following process requires only a tie.
Tie a tie.
Take your phone and switch it to camera mode.
Change the mode of camera to 'shutter' (the one that takes a lot of photos on single click)
Arrange the direction of back camera yourself so that it points to your face.
Now with the same hand, grab tie too.
Place your camera held hand from one side.
Soon after clicking, move your hand through the path tie forwards you.
Please have a lot of trials from bottom, in front of your nose and forehead angle until you are satisfied.

At last, you could remove tie from photos. Since it is only said that you require 360 degree photos of your head, tie will not indulge in them.